# How do I include a number in the lyrics? LilyPond

Tags: lilypond

I'm trying to write intervals underneath notes in LilyPond.  Just something simple like: P5, M3, m2, d5.  I thought the lyrics environment would work, but it ignores the numbers.  Is there a way to escape the numbers so they are included as text in the lyrics?  I tried P\5 but that doesn't work.  Or maybe there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 9):

Numbers are interpreted as durations.  To have them interpreted as lyric words, include them in quote marks.  So basically

```
\addlyrics { "P5" "M3" "m2" "d5" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps insert them as you would insert text markups on notes, e.g. change `c4` to `c4_\markup{P5}`. Or `c4^\markup{P5}` if you want the markup to appear above the note.

Comment: A reasonable approach (+1).  However, note that the markups for different notes wouldn't necessarily be vertically aligned under this approach, which may or may not be a problem.